# My life has been going downhill for about five years. (Is this idiomatic?)

Tags: sentence-meaning

> My life has been going downhill for about five years.

If my life is terrible for almost five years. can I say the sentence above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if your quality of life has been decreasing that whole time. If it got bad and then continued to be the same amount of badness you might not want to use it, and go for something like "I've been stuck in a rut for five years" or "My life went downhill five years ago and it's been the same ever since."